# If Universe Factory Fails, Where To Next?

Tags: discussion, blog

Someone on the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange--I'm not going to name who--suggested that I put my alternate world on the Universe Factory blog.  However, she warned me that that site doesn't get a lot of comments, so I have to find a backup plan on a worldbuilding site or blog (**other than Reddit, thank you very much**) where I can describe the geography, geology and other big aspects of my world and get feedback.

Any idea where that might be?

Comment: Could always run your own...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek How?

Comment: Wordpress or blogger? And if it works out you can just point a proper domain at it. A *lot* of professional authors do this

Comment: Please join in supporting and publicizing the blog and we won't have to worry about it.

Comment: @James  Which blog?  Or are we still talking Universe Factory?

Comment: @JohnWDailey Yes, Universe Factory.

Comment: @James  Where do I go to support and publicize it?

Answer (score 3):

Universe Factory isn't going away, nor is content posted there.  I suppose Medium (the platform) could fail, but it seems unlikely.

Getting feedback through comments is a different matter.  No matter where you post, most people who read don't comment.  Are there places with larger potential audiences?  Certainly; we need to work harder on promoting Universe Factory (and keeping the posts coming).  Of course, there might also be more competition for attention on other sites, so you have to consider that too.

I'm afraid I don't have suggestions for other blogs to post on, sorry.  I'm focusing on this one.

Comment: Can I just say that your writing is fantastic and makes me smile? :)

Comment: Thanks @James!  There's plenty of room for others to join in the fun too. :-)